# Email: Putting View in browser link in an image

Tags: html, email, html-email

I am developing an email and the designer updated the design to include the "View in browser" link an in the header image. At the top of the email is a full-width banner image. In the top-right of this image the designer put the text "View in browser".

Theoretically, I could slice up the image and only make the top-right where the "View in browser" text an image wrapped in a link tag.

The obvious reason not to do that in my mind is that the image will be blocked by default, but is there an recommended solution for designing the "View in browser" part of the email? The designer doesn't like the idea of putting plain "View in browser" copy on top of the email (he's not very experienced with email design, he comes from the world of print).

Comment: Can you include a preview of the intended design and any code examples you have?

Answer (score 0):

**When slicing the design, is there any way you can isolate the "View in browser" in its own slice?**

> Theoretically, I could slice up the image

I used to slice up images from emails designed by print designers. Not sure if this will work with your current design, but I used to **slice up the design in Photoshop in a way that put any block of text in its own slice**. Afterwards,  go into the sliced HTML, remove the image tag of the text, and recreate the text in HTML/CSS. This will keep integrity of the layout and design is kept and hopefully make the print designer happy.